# Convert String expression to actual working instance expression

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, expression, scala-quasiquotes

I am trying to convert an expression in Scala that is saved in database as String back to working code.

I have tried Reflect Toolbox, Groovy, etc. But I can't seem to achieve what I require.

Here's what I tried:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val code1 = q"""StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(tstamp,TimestampType,true), StructField(date,DateType,true))"""
val sType = toolbox.compile(code1)().asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

where I need to use the **sType** instance for passing customSchema to csv file for dataframe creation but it seems to fail.

Is there any way I can get the string expression of the StructType to convert into actual StructType instance? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If StructType is from Spark and you want to just convert String to StructType you don't need reflection. You can try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.LegacyTypeStringParser
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType}

import scala.util.Try

def fromString(raw: String): StructType =
  Try(DataType.fromJson(raw)).getOrElse(LegacyTypeStringParser.parse(raw)) match {
    case t: StructType => t
    case _             => throw new RuntimeException(s"Failed parsing: $raw")
  }

val code1 =
  """StructType(Array(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(tstamp,TimestampType,true), StructField(date,DateType,true)))"""
fromString(code1) // res0: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

The code is taken from the `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType` companion object from Spark. You cannot use it directly as it's in private package. Moreover, it uses `LegacyTypeStringParser` so I'm not sure if this is good enough for Production code.

Answer (score 4):

Your code inside quasiquotes, needs to be valid Scala syntax, so you need to provide quotes for strings. You'd also need to provide all the necessary imports. This works:

```
val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  val code1 =
    q"""
       //we need to import all sql types
       import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
       StructType(
           //StructType needs list
           List(
             //name arguments need to be in proper quotes
             StructField("id",IntegerType,true), 
             StructField("name",StringType,true),
             StructField("tstamp",TimestampType,true),
             StructField("date",DateType,true)
           )
       )
      """
val sType = toolbox.compile(code1)().asInstanceOf[StructType]

println(sType)
```

But maybe instead of trying to recompile the code, you should consider other alternatives as serializing struct type somehow (perhaps to JSON?).

Comment: I was obtaining the schema from the table in which the entry were stored from df.schema.toString. This works but a lot of replace and additional imports would be required inside the quasiString itself. I appreciate the solution though, thank you (: